# Shared Child ViewModel To ShellViewmodel on caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

How does a child ViewModel share DataGrid.selectedItem information to parent ViewModel in Caliburn.Micro?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Event Aggregators](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator) for the purpose. In your current Scenario, you could start by declaring a Message object which would be used to pass the information between the Child and Parent View Models.

```
public class SelectedItemChangedMessage<T>
{
    public T SelectedItem;
}
```

To publish the message, you can use EventAggregator class. For example, you could do the following from ChildViewModel.

```
public class ChildViewModel
{
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        public ChildViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }
        public void Change()
        {
            _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(new SelectedItemChangedMessage<string>(){ SelectedItem = selectedItem });
        }
}
```

And then, in your ParentViewModel, you would need to subscribe to EventAggregator

```
public class ShellViewModel:Screen, IHandle<SelectedItemChangedMessage<string>>
{
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        }

        public void Handle(SelectedItemChangedMessage<string> message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Item Changed, current selection : {message}");
        }
}
```

Comment: Dear Anu Viswan, I appreciate your time to answer me.

Comment: @PHADEL Glad to help you. If it helped in resolve the issue, kindly mark it as answer so that it would be helpful for others as well